# Have python generate command line parameter

Tags: python, linux, shell

I'm trying to have python generate the input parameter to my command line program (Linux), and simply cannot get it to work.

I know it is something to the effect of

```
./heap0 (python -c 'print "A"*72)
```

but that does not work....

Answer (score 3):

Try `$()`. It takes the output of a command and includes it as a value.

```
./heap0 $(python -c 'print "A"*72')
```

Comment: note that if the python script outputs data with whitespace, the shell will interpret that as multiple arguments.  If you want to interpret the output as a single argument even if it contains space, wrap the whole thing in double quotes:  `"$(python -c '...')"`

Comment: If this was what you needed, why haven't you accepted the answer?